# What model should I use to estimate students underlying ability?

Tags: r, regression, machine-learning, time-series, python

As an experimental project, I'd like to estimate around 1000+ students 'underlying ability' or essentially their likely future performance in tests.

The structure of the experimental data is as follows:

1. Students are grouped into classes (by ability)
2. Students can move up and down between these classes depending on how they perform
3. Each class takes 1 test weekly (all on the same subject) with each student getting a score. Not every student takes a test every week.
4. Each test is only taken once and never repeated or reused
5. Students abilities can change over time

The structure of the data is:
student_id
test_id (the particular ID of the test being taken)
test_group (class - varying from 1:10)
test_score (ranges from 50-100)
date

I'd like to produce a model to estimate:

1. The difficulty of each test relative to each other (i.e. if a randomly selected student takes test A and test B, and scores 10 points less on test B, then test B would be 10 points harder)
2. The underlying ability of the students relative to each other (i.e. if two randomly selected students take the same test at the same time t, what would their scores be relative to each other)

Any thoughts or suggestions on model types/structure would be greatly appreciated!